# The faces in rendered and material mode are shading incorrectly. Some are dark and some are light. All normals are correct

Tags: texturing, shaders, faces, normal-map, remesh

the faces are affected by the light so sometimes they're very bright or very dark. I tried deleting and adding the faces but they change slightly, and not all of them change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP wrote "normals" are correct. The provided answer link just handles about wrong normals.

Comment: can you please provide blend file?

Comment: In mesh properties, expand the normals panel and click on "Clear custom split normals"